# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException при шифровании строки с помощью замены

Tags: java

Задача:

> Зашифровать произвольный открытый текст над латинским алфавитом с помощью шифра однобуквенной замены

Код:

```
String str = "BE_HAPPY";
String[] bytes = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", " " };
int[] key = new int[] { 18, 22, 11, 7, 15, 19, 1, 23, 20, 26, 3, 14, 25, 4, 9, 5, 2, 24, 21, 6, 0, 8, 13, 12, 16, 10, 17 };
String a = "";
String m = "";
for (String ma : str.split("")) {
    m = m + bytes[key[Arrays.asList(bytes).indexOf(ma)]];
}
System.out.print(m);
```

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
>       at L5.lab5.main(lab5.java:24)

Что делать?

Comment: А что вы хотите получить? Что должен сделать ваш код?

Comment: задача по криптографии. должен зашифровать строку.

Comment: Добавьте условие задачи в вопрос, эта информация ускорит получение ответа

Comment: Зашифрувати довільний відкритий текст над латинським алфавітом за
допомогою шифру однобуквеної заміни.

Comment: задание сделала вручную, но нужно ещё кодом.

Comment: @ВладаИльяшенко у вас проблема с символом `_` - его нет в массиве `bytes`. Что предполагается делать в этом случае?

Answer (score 2):

в массиве `bytes` нет символа подчеркивания, поэтому `Arrays.asList(bytes).indexOf(ma)` возвращает -1. После попытки обратиться к -1 элементу массива `key` выбрасывает `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: Только вот на вопрос "Что делать?" это ответа не даёт. Так что пока автор полное условие задачи не добавит, полноценный ответ не дать.

Comment: @Regent согласен

Comment: спасибо. Все верно_)

Comment: @ВладаИльяшенко если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано, проблема в символе `_`, для которого нет соответствия в "таблице шифрования".

Позволю себе предположить, что символы, которых нет в "таблице шифрования", должны оставаться в первозданном виде. Тогда, с учетом небольшой оптимизации, код может выглядеть так:

```
String str = "BE_HAPPY";
Character[] chars = new Character[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' ' };
List<Character> charsList = Arrays.asList(chars);
int[] key = new int[] { 18, 22, 11, 7, 15, 19, 1, 23, 20, 26, 3, 14, 25, 4, 9, 5, 2, 24, 21, 6, 0, 8, 13, 12, 16, 10, 17 };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
for (char ch : str.toCharArray())
{
    int charIndex = charsList.indexOf(ch);
    char resultChar = charIndex >= 0 ? chars[key[charIndex]] : ch;
    sb.append(resultChar);
}
System.out.println(sb.toString()); //WP_XSFFQ
```

Answer (score 0):

предполагаю, что шифр и текст - часть задания. также предположим, что скорее всего символ `_` и пробел это одно и то же, т.к. это будет соответствовать условию задачи.

позволю себе немного оптимизировать ваш код и предложить другие варианты решения:

```
@Test
public void test()
{
    String str = "BE_HAPPY";
    // с массивом примитивов будет удобнее работать 
    char[] bytes = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 
        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '_' };

    int[] key = { 18, 22, 11, 7, 15, 19, 1, 23, 20, 26, 3, 14, 25, 4, 9, 5, 2, 24, 21, 6, 0, 8, 13, 12, 16, 10, 17 };
    // а зачем была нужна эта переменная? 
    // String a = "";

    // см ниже. строим словарь для варианта 1
    char[] caesar = new char[255];
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        caesar[bytes[i]] = bytes[key[i]];
    }

    // запомним длину строки чтобы не вызывать метод в цикле
    int n = str.length();
    // будем складывать все в буффер(ы)
    StringBuilder m = new StringBuilder(n);
    StringBuilder m1 = new StringBuilder(n);
    StringBuilder m2 = new StringBuilder(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // берем символ прямо из строки не заморачиваясь разбиванием строки на массив
        char ma = str.charAt(i);
        // вариант 0: сканируем массив символов не переводя его в список каждую итерацию
        for(int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            if(ma == bytes[j]) {
                m.append(bytes[key[j]]);
                break;
            }
        }
        // тут есть альтернативы:
        // вариант 1. если надо было бы зашифровать большой текст, то вместо сканирования лучше использоваит словарь
        m1.append(caesar[ma]);
        // конец варианта 1
        // вариант 2. если мы уверены, что алфавит всегда латиница по порядку, то можно использовать смещение символа
        int offs; // 
        if(ma >= 'A' && ma <= 'Z')
            offs = ma - 'A'; 
        else
            offs = bytes.length-1;
        m2.append(bytes[key[offs]]);
        // конец варианта 2

    }

    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(m1);
    System.out.println(m2);
}
```